# 301 redirect not working ( another one, I know)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Yes, I checked the related questions posted in SO, but could not find something that would help me.

My .htaccess has plenty of redirects already, and they work fine, but  this one is giving me the go around.

I had a URL like:

```
http://example.com/comp_all.php?vid_mod=529
```

which I changed to a more friendly one:

```
http://example.com/comparatif-voiture/Audi/A4/529
```

In order to accomplish that I added the following rule within .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?comparatif-voiture [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([0-9]+$) /comp_all.php?vid_mod=$1 [L]
```

And that works fine, as well.

Now, I want to have the 'old and ugly' URL still sitting out there to be redirect to the 'nice' ones.

I tried the following:

```
Redirect 301 /comp_all.php?vid_mod=529 http://example.com/comparatif-voiture/Audi/A4/529
```

But that does not work. It just shows the 'ugly' URL.

It does not matter whether I placed the above redirect before or after the Rewrite Rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use query string in `Redirect` directive. You need `RewriteCond` in `mod_rewrite` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+comp_all\.php\?vid_mod=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /comparatif-voiture/Audi/A4/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^comparatif-voiture/.+?/([0-9]+)/?$ /comp_all.php?vid_mod=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**PS:** I have also simplified your other rule.

Comment: Thanks, anubhava. That was it. I did not know about the use of query string on redirect. Much appreciated. Cheers.